# Unitarity of linear operator and Its matrix representation

Tags: operator-theory

I've found an exercise in my professor's notes about linear operators that has been giving me some trouble; the exercise reads:

> Let $\mathbf{x}  = (x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_{N-1})^{T} \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and let $\mathcal{U}$ be the linear operator whose action on $\mathbf{x}$ is the following: $$ u_k = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}F_{kn}x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}e^{-\frac{i2\pi kn}{N}}x_n,\hspace{0.4cm} k = 0,1,2,...,N-1$$
> Show that $\mathcal{U}$ is a unitary operator.

My first thought was trying to prove directly that $\langle \mathcal{U}x; \mathcal{U}y\rangle = \langle \mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}\rangle$, where $\langle;\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product and $\mathbf{x,y}$ are two arbitrary vectors of $\mathbb{C}^N$. This proved to be very tedious, therefore I switched strategy, namely determining the matrix representation $\hat{U}$ of $\mathcal{U}$. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do this. Hence, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. The solution to this problem is not given anywhere, so any possible solving method or even hint is more than gladly accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to verify the result for a basis; we will choose the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then

$$\langle{U\mathbf{e}_i, U\mathbf{e}_j\rangle} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k < N} F_{ki}\overline{F_{kj}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k < N} \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi k (j - i)}{N}\right) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } i \neq j \\ 1 &\text{if } i = j \end{cases}.$$